# A value of type 'Set<Row>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, for-loop, widget

After running this inside my widget tree:

```
List<List<Widget>> widgets;
/***/
Column(
  children: [
    for (List<Widget> range in (widgets as List<List<Widget>>)) {
      Row(children: range),
    }
  ]
)
```

I got this error:

`Error: A value of type 'Set<Row>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this remove`{` USED FOR THE FOR LOOP  bracket

```
 for (List<Widget> range in (widgets as List<List<Widget>>))
        Row(children: range),
```

> Set or map? The syntax for map literals is similar to that for set
> literals. Because map literals came first, {} defaults to the Map
> type. If you forget the type annotation on {} or the variable it’s
> assigned to, then Dart creates an object of type Map<dynamic, dynamic[dart tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators)

### Tip

Also we can use like this

```
Column(children: [
      ...widgets.map((e) {
        return Row(children: e);
      }),
      
    ]);
```

Comment: thanks it's working, but why doesn't it work with the brakets?

Comment: See my response that explain the error

Answer (score 0):

That's because you try to affect something like [[...]] to column children instead of [], try something like that :

```
Column(children: widgets.map(element) => Row(children: element));
```